# How to split 2 arrays to generate URLs in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an existing html file where I have 2 variables which holds large amount of text data separated by spaces(blanks). I want to read both of them as arrays and for each element of 2nd array it should generate a link with  to a URL ending with each element of the 1st array.

This should ideally take 1st element of first array and 1st element of second array and formulate URL so that 1st element of second array is wrapped as  with 1st element of first array.

For Example,

```html
array1 = "${entry.metas['identifiers']}" // 1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 .... [n entries]
array2 = "${entry.metas['titles']}" // cat dog lion tiger .... [same as of array1]

split.array1 = [ " " ];
split.array2 = [ " " ];

for each array2 element positions,
<a href="http://myapps.servername.com/framename.jsp?&id=split.array1"> split.array2 </a>
```

The html should display each link with a space or newline as:

```html
<a href="http://myapps.servername.com/framename.jsp?&id=1.1"> cat </a> &nbsp;
<a href="http://myapps.servername.com/framename.jsp?&id=2.1"> dog </a> &nbsp;
<a href="http://myapps.servername.com/framename.jsp?&id=3.1"> lion </a> &nbsp;
<a href="http://myapps.servername.com/framename.jsp?&id=4.1"> tiger </a> &nbsp;
```

Sorry I did not include proper html tags/syntax, but hopefully my question is clear.

Comment: You want us to write that code? Or...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.split` to split create the arrays and then use a `DocumentFragment` and `document.createElement` to generate the links.

```
var identifiers = "1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1";
var titles = "cat dog lion tiger";
var url = "http://myapps.servername.com/framename.jsp?&id=";

var identifiersArr = identifiers.split(" ");
var titlesArr = identifiers.split(" ");

var result = new DocumentFragment();
var parent = document.body;

// Loop through the identifiers array and build a link element. Then append it as a child of "parent";
for(var i = 0; i < identifiersArr.length; ++i) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url + identifiersArr[i];
  link.textContent = titlesArr[i] || 'no title';
  result.appendChild(link);
}
parent.appendChild(result);
```

Comment: This is working fine, the URL gets generated like <cat dog lion tiger> all as one URL in browser, but they are clickable individually. This is almost done.

Now all I need is to separate this links in display so that each link <cat> <dog> <lion> <tiger> gets a space separator and becomes individually URL not a whole as one.

Thanks Cyrix for this code.

Comment: It's generating one link node for each of your links, for the styling and spacing you have to use css, you can always extend this code for example to set a class on the link like: `link.classList.add('my-link')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let s1 = "1.1 1.2 1.3";
let s2 = "cat dog lion";
let a1 = s1.split(" ");
let a2 = s2.split(" ");
for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
  let url = '<a href="http://myapps.servername.com/framename.jsp?&id=';
  url += a1[i] + '">' + a2[i] + '</a>';
  console.log(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Nix for your efforts. I really appreciate your help. I am a bit closer to follow Cyrix though.